# How to enable Auto-Keywords completion for RIDE on MAC?

Tags: macos, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have installed RIDE on MAC (WxPython 3.0.2, Python 2.7.10).

I am able to write tests and execute them.

However, is there a way to get the list of available keywords (or Auto-Keyword completion feature) in RIDE?

Should I import any specific library?

Comment: Theres no library which handles your keyword listing / auto-complete function

Comment: But I don't see any such auto-complete function.

Comment: I tried keys CTRL+SPACE and CTRL+ALT+SPACE, but that doesn't list any built-in or available functions.

Comment: It is only available within the "grid mode" of RIDE. The text mode does not support it - it seems

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get auto-complete via the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is to use the "grid mode" of RIDE. **NOT** the "text edit mode"

I have just tested this, and within the text mode, when I typed "lo" it did nothing when I used the shortcut.
But when I did the same thing within the grid mod, it gave me a list of keywords to use (`${LOG_FILE}`, `log`, `log many`, `log to console`, etc)

So if you want to autocomplete your keywords, either use a different IDE (Pycharm for example) or use the grid mode within RIDE

[Reference](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/How-To)

EDIT:

Not really autocompelte but a nice feature - If you press <kbd>F5</kbd> it will bring up a list of all the keywords which you can search for.

Not exactly what you are looking for, but its nice non the less.

Comment: Yes, I had tried in grid mode itself. But couldn't see anything as such.

Comment: if you do not have a list of KWs this could mean that RF is not installed or RIDE did not discovered RF properly. There should be at least BuildIn KWs. If you need source based editor with coloring,code completion and validation, check RED.

Answer (score 1):

You should not import a specific library to see context help for keywords.
If the keywords are found they will show in blue color.
I believe the key for Mac should be `Apple Command Key + Space`. See Help->Shortcut Keys.
(there has been problems with Mac keys before)